# Why am i unable to load wordcloud in spyder (v 3.3.4)?

Tags: python

Whatever I do, I just cannot use wordcloud in Anaconda - spyder

```
    import wordcloud
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-104-dc1828f2a80e>", line 1, in <module>
    import wordcloud

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wordcloud'
```

After doing some research, I realised that I need to install packages through shell program. So I installed wordcloud using pip command

```
C:\Users\1025990\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts>pip install wordcloud
Collecting wordcloud
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/95/d260ce89441d1f28192fa5a0a016f547829517b11cabe0079ab91c56f6cd/wordcloud-1.5.0.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.6.1 in c:\users\1025990\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from wordcloud) (1.16.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\1025990\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from wordcloud) (6.0.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: wordcloud
  Building wheel for wordcloud (setup.py) ... done
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\1025990\AppData\Local\pip\Cache\wheels\0a\24\57\899dc50402fef8c355561bcfadfe36879def229e6d97424281
Successfully built wordcloud
Installing collected packages: wordcloud
  WARNING: The script wordcloud_cli.exe is installed in 'c:\users\1025990\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed wordcloud-1.5.0
```

I understand that the warnings have nothing to do with the installation as changing the environment variables will eliminate it. I have done that (but not posting here)

After doing that I executed the shell command again

```
C:\Users\1025990\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts>pip install wordcloud
Requirement already satisfied: wordcloud in c:\users\1025990\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.6.1 in c:\users\1025990\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from wordcloud) (1.16.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\1025990\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from wordcloud) (6.0.0)
```

I updated the setup tools in the shell as well

```
C:\Users\1025990\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts>pip install -U setuptools
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in c:\users\1025990\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (41.0.1)
```

Now I check whether I can use wordcloud in spyder, so I run the command again

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-105-021e0a03a31f>", line 1, in <module>
    from wordcloud import WordCloud

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wordcloud'
```

I don't understand what I am missing. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

is it possible that you have multiple python instances and installed it to another one than you are actually using? That's a common cause for this kind of problem.

get your actual version in your python console via `import sys` `print(sys.executable)` and check the site-package folder of this path for your module.

Comment: I dont understand your second part of the comment "check the site-package folder of this path for your module"

Comment: _C:\Users\1025990\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe_ is the output of **print(sys.executable)**

Comment: there should be a bolder `C:\Users\1025990\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages` This folder contains all the modules installed to the python version you are using

Comment: i just checked your log and found this line `Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\1025990\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from wordcloud) (6.0.0)` So the module should actually be there. I try to reproduce it

Comment: ok. it worked for me. I still guess there might be a confusen between different python versions. Can you try `pip3 install wordcloud` and ensure that `sys.version` is 3.X as well?

Comment: `pip3 install wordcloud` gives the same output as `Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\1025990\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from wordcloud) (6.0.0)` and the `sys.version` is `3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]` . However, I am unable to use the package in Spyder IDE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195908/discussion-between-vinay-billa-and-raphael).